# Can't install pip packages when building a Windows docker container

Tags: python, docker, pip, docker-for-windows

I am having issues when installing pip packages on a Windows docker while building.
When running the requirements.txt file, I get the following error messages:

```
Step 4/6 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in c0262814b463
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021949AB99F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/altgraph/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002194972A980>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/altgraph/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021949728B50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/altgraph/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002194972BF70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/altgraph/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021949729C90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/altgraph/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement altgraph==0.17.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for altgraph==0.17.2
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

I already tried using the `--network=host` option, however, this gives me the message `network host not found`.

**dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.10
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ADD . c:/src/app
WORKDIR c:/src/app
ENV PYTHONPATH c:/src/app:$PYTHONPATH

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

I need to use a Windows docker container because the package pywin32 is used, which is apparently a Windows specific package. A Linux docker container has no problems with importing the packages with pip, but gives an error when installing pywin32.

How can I make this work with the Windows docker?

Comment: error says getaddrinfo - it means that the env you are trying to instal the package in - fails to resolve the name into ip ..

Comment: and wild guess from someone who has not used docker on windows: add your dns servers to daemon.json of docker itself ..

Comment: @MiCo did you find the solution? I am facing the same error.

Comment: @ManishShegokar unfortunately I didn't

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting the dns in the docker daemon configuration file resolved the issue (Refer to [these instructions](https://stefanmaron.com/2020/07/04/how-to-fix-problems-with-docker-dns-resolution/)).

Currently using

```
{
  "dns": [
    "8.8.8.8"
  ]
}
```